# Web scraping with VBA to fetch material prices

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

For the past few days I've been working on a VBA macro that will pull materiel prices from different pages and I've made the macro work on three different sites, but on the forth one I just can't seem to wrap my mind around it. Hope someone can help.

Here is a snippet of the source-code (Would post the link but you're requried a login).

I would like to return the value `kr. 310,00` as of forth line

```
<div class="product-prices" id="MainContent_ucProductDetails_articlePrices">
    <table class="pricesTable" style="border-collapse:collapse;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td class="description">Indkøbspris:</td><td>kr. 310,00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td class="description">Rabat:</td><td>38%</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td class="description">Listepris:</td><td>kr. 500,00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td class="description">Salgspris:</td><td>kr. 500,00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td class="description">Afgift i alt:</td><td>kr. 0,00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td class="description last">Pris per</td><td class="last">1 STK</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table></div>
```

And here is the part of my failed code trying to get the value.

```
    Do While ie.busy
       Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set objCollection = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("priceTable")

    i = 0

    While i < objCollection.Length
        MsgBox objCollection(i).innertext
        i = i + 1
    Wend
```

When i step through the code it skips the While...Wend and I can't seem to figure out why.

Hope someone can help out,

/T

Comment: Write `debug.print objCollection.Length` before entering the While loop. What is appearing on the immediate window?

Comment: What text is displayed with "MsgBox objCollection(i).innertext"?

Comment: @D.O. per the OP the loop doesn't even iterate once..

Comment: `<table class="pricesTable"` & `ClassName("priceTable")` do not match

Comment: OOOHHH!!! this "s"!!!!!! :- ) And the text we need is in "description" class.

Comment: It was all due to the stupid S i missed in the class name! Thanks @Glitch_Doctor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go like this to get the price. The easiest way:

```
For Each price In html.getElementsByClassName("product-prices")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")
    If InStr(price.innerText, "Indkøbspris:") > 0 Then
        MsgBox price.NextSibling.innerText
    End If
    Exit For
Next price
```

Result:
kr. 310, 00

Comment: But I think he need all the other prices, not only this one.

Comment: See this line `I would like to return the value kr. 310,00 as of forth line` which is clearly mentioned in OP's description. Before making any comment please care to go through the description.

Comment: yea only needed 310,00 this works like a charm! My own code would have taken all the values in the table if I didn't miss a "s" in the classname! Thanks!